# Access web service in an IP V6 server from an IP V4 client

Tags: java, android, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I want to send request to a Web Server hosted in IP V6 protocol from a client working in IP V4 protocol. Is that possible?

I have created a web service to run on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1. The device returns an IP V6 address. I could not use that address to send request from my PC running Windows XP.

Please help me with a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IPv4 and IPv6 are two separate protocols, and an IPv4-only device can not talk directly to an IPv6-only device. One solution is to install a proxy server that speaks both IPv4 and IPv6 and can facilitate a connection. Another solution is to install a NAT46 gateway that NATs the IPv4 request to the IPv6 server. But the best and most future-proof solution is to make sure every device speaks IPv6 so that you can communicate directly. In the future this will be necessary anyway.

Windows XP is a bit old, but you can install IPv6 on your network adapter manually. Microsoft provides instructions at http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_ip_v6_pro_inst.mspx